# React change lottie animation src on button click

Tags: reactjs, lottie

I managed to change to create a toggle between 2 images, yew but for my next trick how would go about creating the same but instead of images i use lottie animations which change on button click? I can't seem to find any help online to achieve this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import PurchaseButton from "../buttons/PurchaseButton"
import { themes } from "../styles/ColorStyles"
import { H1, MediumText } from "../styles/TextStyles"

const Worksites = {
  Garside: {
    img: "/images/worksites/worksite1.png",
  },
  OakandOcean: {
    img: "/images/shots/hero-shot2.png",
  },
}

export default function GallerySection() {
  const [selectedWorksites, setSelectedWorksites] = useState(Worksites.Garside)

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <TextWrapper>
          <Lockup>
            <Title>See how trades work in GoTradie</Title>
          </Lockup>
          <Description>
            You don’t have to believe us checkout some of the tradies already
            using Gotradie
          </Description>
          <ul>
            <ButtonGroup>
              <PurchaseButton
                title="Garside Electrcial & Solar"
                className={`${
                  selectedWorksites === Worksites.Garside ? "active" : "static"
                }`}
                onClick={() => setSelectedWorksites(Worksites.Garside)}
              />

              <PurchaseButton
                title="Oak & Ocean Building"
                className={`${
                  selectedWorksites === Worksites.OakandOcean
                    ? "active"
                    : "static"
                }`}
                onClick={() => setSelectedWorksites(Worksites.OakandOcean)}
              />
            </ButtonGroup>
          </ul>
        </TextWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
      <ImageWrapper>
        {selectedWorksites ? (
          <div>
            <img src={selectedWorksites.img} alt="" />
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </ImageWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```